# Retrieving video from firebase storage but no video is displayed

Tags: android-studio, video, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve a video from firebase storage but if i try it with the code underneath the video doesn't get displayed and the videoView stays empty.

```
// Adding post image to linear layout
                                ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                        //Adding video to linear layout
                                        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(uri));

                                        //Creating new video view for displaying video
                                        VideoView videoView = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
                                        videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);

                                        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
                                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                                        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

                                        videoView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                                        videoView.start();

                                        //Adding video view to linear layout
                                        linearLayout3.addView(videoView);
                                    }
                                });
```

Anyone that has a solution?

Comment: It has come to my notice that if I try the same code on a videoview that already exists in a XML-file that the code above does work. But if i try it again on the dynamically created videoview like the code above then it doesn't work anymore.